# implicit declaration of function 'yyback' is invalid in C99

Tags: xcode, macos, bison, lex

Why is my lex build failing on Macos?

This is the error:

```
    lex_yy.c:71:6: error: implicit declaration of function 'yywrap' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
if (yywrap()) return(0); break;



    lex_yy.c:68:14: error: implicit declaration of function 'yylook' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   while( (nstr = yylook()) >= 0)
```

and

```
 lex_yy.c:874:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'yyback' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                                        while(yyback((*lsp)->yystops,-*yyfnd) != 1 && lsp > yylstate){
```

Comment: Can you include some details about the compile commands you used?

Comment: What lex are you using?

Comment: This source code is for lua version 1

Comment: cc -O2 -I.   -c -o lex_yy.o lex_yy.c

Comment: "Lua 1.1 was released on 08 Jul 1994." So perhaps not surprising that it won't compile with C99. You could try `-std=c90`.

Comment: I took a quick look at Lua 1.1, and I think you're going to need to do a bit of work to build it with a modern toolchain. Why do you want it?

Comment: not work `cc -O2 -I. -std=c90   -c -o lex_yy.o lex_yy.c` on macOS

Comment: @cunknown: I know. I said that. You're going to need to do some work to build Lua 1.1 with a modern toolchain. The original Lua was written for SunOS, and it makes a lot of assumptions which are not valid on MacOS or Linux. Why do you want to compile it? You could use a more modern version; Lua 3.1 and newer should compile just fine.

Comment: I do not think so because I tried it on Linux before it worked ,
It does not work only on mac